# String to float issues with absolute value

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program solves quadratic equations and finds the amount of real solutions. I was trying to tune up my program by cleaning things up such as, if the input of a,b or c is either 1 or -1, display the function as `x^2+x+c` (if user puts in one for all) or `-x^2-x-c` (if user picks -1 for all of them.) This should be the case for all positive or negative numbers.
So in reality, it should put out if a is 6, b is -7, and c is 4, it should output as `6x^2-7x+4`, but currently it is `6x^2+-2x+4`. I know something has to  be done with the absolute value function, but just trying to fix the -1 and 1 situation gives me errors with converting string to float.
The error I get is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danco/PycharmProjects/ECE 122/a_hermon_ECE122project1.py", line 26, in 
    x = float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

I tried using the absolute value function, but the errors with the float to string before using it are still carrying over. This is all in the evaluate_quad_function.

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
import math
def evaluate_quad_function(a, b, c, x):
    f_of_x = a*(x**2) + (b * x) + c
    return f_of_x  # return the calculated result
print("Welcome to the Quadratic Solver for f(x)=ax^2+bx+c")
a = input("Enter Value for a:")
b = input("Enter Value for b:")
c = input("Enter Value for c:")
# cannot do math on string, convert to float
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
f_x0= a*((-b)/(2*a)**2) + (b * (-b)/(2*a)) + c

if a == 1 and b == 1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ","x**2 +","x +", c, sep="")

if a == -1 and b == -1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ","-x**2 -","x +", c, sep="")
else:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 +", b, "x +", c, sep="")
x = input("Enter Value for x:")
x = float(x)

fx = evaluate_quad_function(a, b, c, x)
print("F"+"("+str(x)+"=", str(fx))
temp = input("\nPress Enter to continue...")  # wait

x0 = -b/(2*a)
x0 = float(x0)
if a>0:
    print("f(x) has a minimum at "+ str(x0)+" with a value f(x0)="+ str(f_x0))
else:
    print("f(x) has a maximum at " + str(x0) + " with a value f(x0)=" + str(f_x0))
temp = input("\nPress Enter to continue...")  # wait

def compute_discriminate():
    print("Solving for f(x) = 0")
    d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print("Discriminant is", str(d))
    if d > 0:
        (print("Two Real Solutions",str(x1), "and", str(x2) ))
    if d == 0:
        print("One real solution:", str(x0))
    else:
        print("No real solution.")
print("\nThanks for using Quadratic Solver!, come back soon.")
print(compute_discriminate())
```

Comment: Please paste the error traceback (it literally tells you exactly where the issue is). Also please space your code properly. You should have a space before and after almost all operators.

Comment: That is the error code. Sorry about the space, I'm new to Python and programming as a whole.

Comment: Put it in the question not the comments please.

Comment: What inputs do you use to get the error? I can't replicate it.

Comment: I used -1, -1, and 6 for a, b and c respectively.

Comment: What did you use for `x`? I still can't get the error with those inputs.

Comment: turns out it was a small issue, but I am still having issues with the absolute value bit with making sure it doesnt say +- when you use a negative value for b or c

Comment: `x0 = float(x0)` isn't necessary; `-b/(2*a)` is already a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function to print + or - before a number.

Try this:

```
def print_sign(x):
    # check the sign if positive or negative
    return '+' if x > 0 else '-'

print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 ",print_sign(b), abs(b), "x ", print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")
```

Result:
Function is: f(x)= 1.0x**2 -4.0x +3.0

====EDIT====
Replace these lines with the code above

```
if a == 1 and b == 1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ","x**2 +","x +", c, sep="")

if a == -1 and b == -1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ","-x**2 -","x +", c, sep="")
else:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 +", b, "x +", c, sep="")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. YOu are saying for this function to be added or to replace the current function I have now? Because I tried your function and it is still doing the +- sign on the equation

Comment: You can replace the six lines with the codes I gave you